# How to properly configure plugins in tmux?

Tags: tmux, tmux-plugin-manager

All plugin installation examples use the configuration file `~/.tmux.conf` as if it exists. I don't have this file anywhere, the attempt to create it manually and add plugins is simply ignored.

Where is this file located?

Why the attempt to install [the plugin manager](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tpm) is simply ignored.

I'm cloning a repository.

```
git clone https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tpm ~/.tmux/plugins/tpm
```

I create an `~/.tmux.conf` file with my hands and insert the following contents into it.

```
# List of plugins
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tpm'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-sensible'


# Initialize TMUX plugin manager (keep this line at the very bottom of tmux.conf)
run '~/.tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm'
```

I specify the path to the files and restart tmux. Nothing happens, I tried to add [different plugins](https://draculatheme.com/tmux) and nothing.

```
tmux source ~/.tmux.conf
```

My final configuration file:

```
# List of plugins
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tpm'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-sensible'

set -g @plugin 'dracula/tmux'    

# Initialize TMUX plugin manager (keep this line at the very bottom of tmux.conf)
run '~/.tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm'
```

Answer (score 0):

The TMP does not start automatically. Did you press

```
<prefix>-I
```

?

With default settings that would be

```
ctrl-b + 'I'
```